# What's up with this serial upvoting?

Tags: support

There was a user who appears to have recently benefited from serial upvoting - gaining about 200 rep within the space of three minutes. I checked the user's rep chart, and it shows that there was, at one point later on, "-50 - serial upvoting reversed."

I don't think that only 5 upvotes (for they were all on answers) were part of the serial upvoting, yet only 5 were reversed. What's up with this? If there appears to be serial upvoting on a large number of questions, why has only part of it been reversed?

Comment: Hard to say. AFAIK they don't really say how serial up/downvoting is qualified/quantified by the automated system, to discourage people from trying to find ways around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not really appropriate for moderators to comment on these things. If you believe that there is serial upvoting or downvoting, you should flag an affected question or answer, contract a moderator, or contact a community manager.

The only other help I can offer is the help page on serial voting reversal:

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I did flag one of the affected questions for moderator attention; I'll see what happens.

Comment: Also, checking the user's rep, the serial upvoting appears to have been thoroughly addressed by the mods.